# Using Virtual Page Views to strip URL parameters from FB Pixel data

Tags: facebook-pixel

With Facebooks recent updates flagging potential personally identifiable data being collected by the FB Pixel, we've ended up getting flagged for having latitude and longitude in our URL parameters on our search result pages (which is a geographic search based on a submitted address). This data does not match user locations, but FB obviously don't care about nuances.

From what I can tell, data from sessions that include URLs with lat/lng in the parameters, are excluded from the data used for targeting our ads, which has significantly affect performance. To rectify this I'd like to strip URL parameters from the URLs being collected by FB.

One suggestion given to me is to edit the FB pixel code and replace `fbq('track', 'PageView');` with a Virtual Page View. Would this work? Will a Virtual Page View prevent URL parameters being passed? Or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 5):

So we tested this out, replacing `fbq('track', 'PageView');` with `fbq('trackCustom', 'VirtualPageView', {url: fbpixelUrlWithoutLatLng()});` (with a function to strip out lat/lng from the URL).

While this call works exactly as intended, Facebook is still receiving the full URL (I suspect they ingest the URL from HTTP headers in addition to any page view events triggered).

I'm not really sure that there's any other viable solutions to this without having to re-engineer/re-implement the URLs (either passing the parameters in another way, or obfuscating them).

Comment: I'm getting the same for `?emailAddress=...` but it's coming from an unsubscribe link in an email that the user clicks and it already contains their email. Really seems like there should to be a way to do something like `fbq(...., { ignoreParameters: ['emailAddress'] })` and have them stripped off for you.

Comment: we are having the same issue, have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way that seems to work: https://gtmserverside.net/2023/03/modifying-redacting-query-string-parameters-before-tracking-pixels-fire-e-g-meta-facebook-google/

Repeating the steps here in case the link dies:

Add a new variable with custom Javascript function:

Name: `JS - Clean Query`

```js
function() {
    return function (uri, key, value) {
        // remove the hash part before operating on the uri
        var i = uri.indexOf('#');
        var hash = i === -1 ? '' : uri.substr(i);
        uri = i === -1 ? uri : uri.substr(0, i);
 
        var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
        var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
 
        if (value === null) {
            // remove key-value pair if value is specifically null
            uri = uri.replace(new RegExp("([?&]?)" + key + "=[^&]*", "i"), '');
            if (uri.slice(-1) === '?') {
                uri = uri.slice(0, -1);
            }
            // replace first occurrence of & by ? if no ? is present
            if (uri.indexOf('?') === -1) uri = uri.replace(/&/, '?');
        } else if (uri.match(re)) {
            uri = uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
        }
        return uri + hash;
    }
}
```

add a HTML-tag with the following code

```html
<script>
  var params_to_clean = ["s", "emailAddress"]; // add sensitive query parameters here
  var new_url = {{Page URL}};
   
  for (var i in params_to_clean) {
    new_url = {{JS - Clean Query}}(new_url, params_to_clean[i], "__redacted__");
  }
  window.history.replaceState({} , "", new_url);
</script>
```

Make sure this tag triggers on `Initialization – All Pages` before any tag that depends on it.

Comment: Any idea how I can customize this script to remove all get parameters without the need to specify each one?

Comment: @simen maybe something like this: `var new_url = {{Page URL}}.split('?')[0]` and then you don't need the loop or the {{JS - Clean Query}} variable. (this is untested)

Comment: @simen basically just this an HTML tag with this: `<script>window.history.replaceState({} , "", {{Page URL}}.split('?')[0]);</script>` (also untested). this drops the parameters entirely, so they wont show up as \__redacted_\_ either, is that a deal-breaker?

Comment: Looks like a good solution. One problem with this might be that if links are sent with gclid or other tracking related data, then that would be removed before tags are fired. Maybe the __redacted__ on specific parameters is better after all.